# How can show some item in my list when bind my list to a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list that bound to a grid. My list items have properties like RunTimeState. The user can select each item in the grid and delete it. When an item is deleted its RunTimeState is set to Deleted. How can I get my grid to not show these deleted items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your item is deleted, you should raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event with property name set to grid data source. And that property should filter the items or the item should be removed from your collection before.

A code can look like this:

```
var myDataSource = ...;

public void DeleteItem(Item item)
{
  item.RunTimeState = RunTimeState.Deleted;
  // you can remove the item from the myDataSource here or filter it later
  PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DataSource"));
}

public IList<Item> DataSource 
{
  get { return myDataSource; }
  // or
  get 
  { 
    return myDataSource.Where(i => i.RunTimeState != RunTimeState.Deleted).ToList(); 
  }
}
```